# MongoDb documents join with inner objects

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 documents named calls and customers
i want to join locationId of calls to customers.location._id

calls

```
      "_id": "5d456560221b9147e4af4b97",
      "customerId": "5d0a3bbfac9470aea56ad619",
      "locationId": "5d11d2c4cba8151f67f735b1",
      "startDateTime": "2019-06-21T05:30:00.000Z",
      "endDateTime": "2019-06-21T06:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

customers

```
      "_id": "5d0a3bbfac9470aea56ad619",
      "locations": [
        {
          "_id": "5d11d2c4cba8151f67f735b1",
          "phone": "9889599999",
          "ext": "91",
          "address": "sad",
          "neighborhood": "sda",
          "city": "punetest",
          "state": "MH",
          "zip": "589365",
          "country": "india",
          "isBillingAddress": false,
          "taxPercentage": 0,
          "type": "Residential",
          "status": "Active",
          "firstName": "A",
          "lastName": "B"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5d11e457cba8151f67f735b3",
          "phone": "969696999",
          "ext": "91",
          "address": "",
          "neighborhood": "",
          "city": "udaipur",
          "state": "raj",
          "zip": "312563",
          "country": "india",
          "isBillingAddress": false,
          "taxPercentage": 0,
          "type": "Residential",
          "status": "Deleted",
          "firstName": "AB",
          "lastName": "CD"
        }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2019-06-19T13:42:23.479Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-06-25T13:39:07.597Z"
    }
```

```
    [
     {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'customers.locations',
          localField: 'locationId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'customers.locations',
        },
      }
     ]);
```

it is not working
I have 2 documents named calls and customers i want to join locationId of calls to customers.location._id

I want output```
{
      "_id": "5d456560221b9147e4af4b97",
      "customerId": "5d0a3bbfac9470aea56ad619",
      "locationId": "5d11d2c4cba8151f67f735b1",
      "location":{"_id": "5d11d2c4cba8151f67f735b1",
          "phone": "9889599999",
          "ext": "91",
          "address": "sad",
          "neighborhood": "sda",
          "city": "punetest",
          "state": "MH",
          "zip": "589365",
          "country": "india",
          "isBillingAddress": false,
          "taxPercentage": 0,
          "type": "Residential",
          "status": "Active",
          "firstName": "A",
          "lastName": "B"}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what you're looking at :

If your `locationId` in **calls** has only one matching `customer.locations._id` in **customer** :

```
 db.getCollection('calls').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'customers',
      localField: 'locationId',
      foreignField: 'locations._id',
      as: 'customersCalls',
    }
  }, { $unwind: '$customersCalls' },
  {
    $project: {
      customerId: 1, locationId: 1, locations: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$customersCalls.locations",
          as: "item",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$item._id", '$locationId'] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id', result: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$result" } }
])
```

else if your `locationId` in **calls** has multiple matching `customer.locations._id` in **customer** :

```
db.getCollection('calls').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'customers',
      localField: 'locationId',
      foreignField: 'locations._id',
      as: 'customersCalls',
    }
  }, { $unwind: '$customersCalls' },
  {
    $project: {
      customerId: 1, locationId: 1, locations: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$customersCalls.locations",
          as: "item",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$item._id", '$locationId'] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id', locations: { $push: { $arrayElemAt: ["$locations", 0] } }, result: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } },
  { $addFields: { 'result.locations': '$locations' } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$result" } }
])
```

Comment: i m performing on calls.. joining calls to customers.. i tried above method but it is not working..

Comment: @vimmi : what's the issue now ? Do you only want the matching document from locations array? Is that the issue ?

Comment: It is joining to customer document and i want to join locations which is inside of customers document.. now you got my point?

Comment: @vimmi : What do you mean by it's joining with customer document ? It's mapping with locations._id, Only issue I'm seeing here is multiple documents in locations(that's because if an element is matched with condition on an array it would return whole array rather than matched element), If you don't need that maybe you need to write conditions or do this operation on customer by $unwind locations array, if it's not the case, then that's $lookup is !!

Comment: I have multiple locations in customers document.. is there any solution to get this done? or i should move locations in different document

Comment: @vimmi : we can still achieve it but it would add additional steps if we query thru calls collection, rather if we do on customer then it would as simple as above, this is because of the nature of arrays !!

Comment: how is that possible

Comment: {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'customers',
          localField: 'locationId',
          foreignField: 'locations._id',
          as: 'customersCalls',
        },
      },
      { unwind: '$customersCalls' },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: '$customersCalls',
          localField: 'locationId',
          foreignField: '$customersCalls.locations._id',
          as: 'test',
        },
      },

Comment: @vimmi : Can you edit your question to give the required o/p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197865/discussion-between-vimmi-and-srinivasy).